# How to perform an action/operation with nextjs API routes and server-side rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

The next.js documentation is very clear about data fetching and how to create dynamic API routes. I wonder what is the correct way to trigger an action/method on the server-side. I.e. if I want to subscribe to a newsletter, there would be a button "Subscribe". When the user clicks the button, the users email address should be inserted into the database as a subscriber.

Based on the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) I would create POST API endpoint by adding this to `pages/api/subscribe.js`:

```js
function signup(emailAddress) {
   // do arbitrary database connection work here and insert into subscriber table
}

export default function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
     signup(req.body.emailAddress)
     res.json({ status: 'ok' })
  }
}
```

Now, in the `onClick()` of the "Susbcribe" button, I could use `fetch()` to send that post request to `/api/subscribe` along with a JSON payload, but the documentation of nextjs [explicitly states not to do that](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching). Also, there  is only `getServerSideProps()` that I could use in the next.js page code - but we do not want to signup a user upon page load, it is a single action/method after which the user should be redirected to a success page.

Additionally, it is obvious that in a client-side component I cannot import `signup()` since it contains server-side nodejs code.

Basically this question boils down to: "Okay, I can fetch data with `getServerSideProps()` without creating a REST API, but how do I perform server-side actions/invocations without creating and calling a REST API upon user interaction?".

Comment: Where does the documentation say not to `fetch` on click? You must trigger the fetch somehow. Also, take a look [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/) for fetching data in react (made by the folks that made next.js)

Comment: fetching data is not an issue here, the issue is performing server-side data manipulation upon user interaction. The part in the docs where it says not to use `fetch()` is: `https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching`. I admit, this refers to when fetching data, not posting/putting/deleting.

Comment: "I could use fetch() to send that post request to /api/subscribe along with a JSON payload" - That's exactly what you should do. What the docs recommend is to not make requests to API routes inside `getStaticProps`/`getServerSideProps` which is not related to your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

After having used Next.js for 1+ years and worked with both App+Pages router, I just have to say there is no such thing in NextJS. Performing server-side mutations is not covered by NextJS.

If you need a React framework that also handles mutations, take a look at [Remix](https://remix.run/).